# Passing a template function into another template function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

So, I have a function, preorder processing, that's meant to execute the function f on each item in each node of a bst. The function is as follows:

```
template <class Item, class Key, class Process>
void preorder_processing(bstNode<Item, Key>*& root, Process f)
{
    if (root == NULL) return; 
    f(root);
    preorder_processing(root->left(), f); 
    preorder_processing(root->right(), f);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I call the class from within the main function, I get an error. The call is preorder_processing(root_ptr, print); and the actual function 'print' is:

```
template<class Item> 
void print(Item a) 
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The error is:

> bstNode.cxx:23: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘`preorder_processing(bstNode<int, long unsigned int>* <unresolved
>   overloaded function type>)`’

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You need to give the declaration of `inorder_processing()` function as well. What is the `print()` function doing ?

Comment: Whoops, I have two of the same error messages, for similar functions and posted the wrong one. My bad. It's preorder_processing() not inorder in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `root->left()` and `root->right()` should be returning `bstNode<Item, Key>*` which is an **rvalue pointer**. You cannot assign a non-const reference to a temporary pointer variable.

Change the declaration as below and the compiler error should go:

```
void preorder_processing(bstNode<Item, Key>* root, Process f)
                 //    removed reference  ^^^
```

Moreover, the 2nd parameter `Process f` is not passed any value when you call the function:

```
preorder_processing(root->left(), ???);
```

Comment: That makes sense, and I'll keep it out, but I'm afraid it didn't solve our problem. Didn't change anything, in fact. Exact same error.

Comment: @vanchagreen, have checked the `Process f` parameter as stated in my answer ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I took that out at one point and never put it back in. :\ But, yeah, still not working. It's crashing on the first call to the function. It never gets inside it.

Comment: @vanchagreen, crash is a different problem, where one need to check the logic of the program. Your question was about the compiler error I guess. You can post your full logic in [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to better address it.

Comment: Will they answer it? It looks like more of a place fore optimizations and such? And it wasn't a crash, it was the compiler error I was talking about.